# Find the units of $A$

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]$, $T=\{f(x) \in R \text{ with } f(0) \neq 0\}$ and $A=T^{-1}R$.
>
> Find all units of A.

I assume an element in $A$ is of the form $\frac{a}{b}$ with $a \in R$ and $b\in T$. So we need to find elements such that $\frac{a}{b}\frac{c}{d}=\frac{c}{d}\frac{a}{b}=1$. This holds of course when $ac=bd$. But how do I proceed to find an expression for all the units? I'm a little stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

$T$ is the complement of the prime ideal $(x)$, so you are just localizing at a prime ideal, and therefore $T^{-1}R$ is a local ring. The units are those things outside the unique maximal ideal. Describe those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely rigorous as stated, but to get an idea of what's going on:

If $\frac{a}{b} \frac{c}{d} = 1$ then $\frac{c}{d} = \frac{b}{a}$.  So this inverse $\frac{c}{d}$ exists provided that $a$ is something that's allowed in the denominator of an element of $A$ -- namely, if $a(0) \neq 0$.  (Of course we're assuming that $\frac{a}{b}$ is in lowest terms.)

Comment: So that would mean that the units of $A$ are exactly $A-\{\frac{0}{x}\}$ with $x \in T$, right?

Comment: No.  0/x = 0.  The units in A are the quotients of polynomials with nonzero constant terms.